# Getting 'authentication required' error while pulling jenkins image

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-image

When I tried pulling jenkins images(`docker pull jenkins`) from docker hub,at the time of download it reports the authentication required error.
Please suggest.

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: Needs more code and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Docker version?

Answer (score 2):

Try executing a `docker logout` before pulling the image.
Similar issue [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2645).

It also can be related to server/client time syncrony, so if `docker logout` does not work check if the time of your system is correct (can be in a different timezone). And set it with `sudo date -s "28 NOV 2013 hh:mm:ss"`, you can check the current exact hour [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc).

Comment: Restarting docker fixed it